# How do I create a histogram of the binomial distribution for, say, p=.5 after 10 trials?

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics

I apologize if this is question is too simple, if so it's because I'm a beginner. Anyway, it was easy enough to create a list plot, but I couldn't find out how to create an output that displays the probabilities associated with 0-10 successful trials in a histogram format (so that the heights of the bars represent the probability of x favourable outcomes). This is the list plot:

```
ListPlot[Partition[
  Riffle[Range[0, 10], 
   Map[#/2^10 &, Table[Binomial[10, k], {k, 0, 10}]]], 2], 
 Filling -> Axis]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour). 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking [the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh). (3) Please remember to accept the answer that solves your problem, by clicking the [checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t).  4) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will do. Unfortunately, I can't up-vote any answers yet because of my lack of reputation points (otherwise I would've already done so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a style for such plots that I have used before:

```
makeBinomialPlot[n_, p_] := Module[
  {scale = .9},
  Show[
   ListPlot[
    Table[
     {k, PDF[BinomialDistribution[n, p], k]},
     {k, 0, n}
     ],
    Filling -> Axis,
    FillingStyle -> Black,
    PlotStyle -> PointSize[.015],
    PlotRange -> All,
    Epilog -> {Inset[
       Style[Column[{
          "Binomial probability", "distribution versus", 
          "Gaussian (solid line)", Row[{"N = ", n}], Row[{"p = ", p}],
           Row[{"\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(k\), \(_\)]\) = ", n p}]}], 
        Small], Scaled[scale {1, 1}], {1, 1}]}],
   Plot[
    PDF[NormalDistribution[n p, Sqrt[n p (1 - p)]], k], {k, 0, n},
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Orange, Thickness[.004]],
    PlotRange -> All
    ],
   Frame -> True,
   FrameLabel -> {"k", "P(k)"},
   ImageSize -> 400,
   PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 0}, {0, .04}}
   ]
  ]

params = {{{10, .5}, {10, .15}}, {{100, .5}, {100, .15}}};

GraphicsGrid[Apply[makeBinomialPlot, params, {2}]]
```

[image: sticks]

For the plot, I use `ListPlot` with `Filling -> Axis`.

With this style, a comparison with a continuous distribution looks nice because the discrete values are represented as points whose alignment with the curve can be immediately seen, while at the same time being marked as discrete by the vertical lines.

What I plotted here is the binomial distribution for four different parameters, compared to the normal distribution to illustrate the central limit theorem. The columns differ in the choice of the probability `p`, and the rows differ in the number of trials.

**Edit**

I realized that you may also be interested in the use of `Histogram` for a more "experiment" oriented type of plot. Here I do a large number of random experiments and again make a comparison to the normal distribution (Central Limit Theorem again):

```
compareGaussian[nO_, p_, nS_, ntests_] := Module[
  {p1, p2, data, f, std},
  (* The standard deviation for outcomes in the range {0,1,2,...nO}*)

    std = StandardDeviation[BinomialDistribution[nO, p]];
  (* 
  Create "ntests" lists of random integers, 
  each with "nS" entries drawn from {1,2,...nO}. 
  For each list, calculate the mean value.
  So data contains "ntest" mean values:
  *)
  data = Table[
    N[Mean[
      RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[nO, p], nS]
      ]],
    {ntests}];
  (* Create bins for the histogram: *)
  p1 = Histogram[data,
    {-(nO + 1)/Sqrt[ntests]/2,
     (nO + 1) + (nO + 1)/Sqrt[ntests]/2,
     (nO + 1)/Sqrt[ntests]},
    "ProbabilityDensity"
    ];
  p2 = Plot[
    PDF[NormalDistribution[nO p, std/Sqrt[nS]], x], {x, 1, nO}, 
    PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.004]}];
  Show[p1, p2, 
   Epilog -> {Inset[
      Panel[Grid[{{"m =", ToString[nO]}, {"N =", 
          ToString[
           nS]}, {"\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(σ\), \(~\)]\) = ", 

          ToString[
           N[std/Sqrt[nS], 
            3]]}, {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(N\), \(tests\)]\) = ", 
          ToString[ntests]}}, Alignment -> {Right, Left}]], 
      Scaled[{.77, .9}], {0, 1}]
     },
   Frame -> True,
   FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(k\), \(_\)]\)", 
     "P(\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(k\), \(_\)]\))"},
   PlotRange -> {{0, nO + 1},
     All
     },
   PlotRangePadding -> 0,
   ImageSize -> 360,
   Axes -> None]
  ]

GraphicsGrid[{
  {compareGaussian[24, .5, 1, 500],
   compareGaussian[24, .5, 2, 500]},
  {compareGaussian[24, .5, 5, 500],
   compareGaussian[24, .5, 50, 500]},
  {compareGaussian[24, .5, 50, 5000],
   compareGaussian[24, .5, 100, 5000]}},
 Spacings -> Scaled[0]]
```

[image: experiments]

This takes longer to run because I do many thousands of repetitions to get the statistics for the histograms. The main point here is that I use `Histogram` with the specification for the bins, and the choice `"ProbabilityDensity"` for the presentation style. I added the explanations as comments in the code. There are various parameters: `p` is again the probability, `nO` stands for the number of outcomes.

Comment: Very pretty, thanks very much indeed for your help!